# Crassula tetragona losing leaves

Tags: succulents

[image][image]
Plant had recently started losing leaves.  I’ve had for about 2 months.  Thought it might not be getting enough sun - but is still losing leaves.  What do I do?

Comment: very common to provide too much water and not enough sun. That pot does allow water to drain out the bottom, right?

Comment: Yes. Have used a moisture meter and only give water when st a 0 or 1

Answer (score 1):

I know this late, but for those that also grow this plants and are having difficulties.

This plant is actually Senecio haworthii, Wooly Senecio or Cocoon Plant.  This is not a good plant for a novice succulent owner.  It is very sensitive to being over-watered.  In winter succulents are semi-dormant inside.  Some like this need to stay on the dry side the entire winter season.  This means giving it a good watering then let it dry out and stay dry for a month or more.  Not until the plant start to show stress from being under-watered do you need to water this plant again.

Moisture metres are not reliable, especially in soil that is made for succulents.  Moisture metres function by measuring the electrical resistance between two electrodes.  Electricity moves quickly and easily through water.  When these metres are working correctly; Soil that is high in water will give a high number.  Soil that is low in water will get a low number.   The problem comes when some thing interrupts this current.  If there is something between the electrodes that interrupts the current the metre will read a low number even if the soil is wet.   Soils like those made for succulents are high in matter that interrupts the current like pumice, perlite, rock, bark, wood.  All of these things slow down the current which give you a false reading.

You are better off using something very simple like a bamboo skewer.  Insert a bamboo skewer in the soil.  Leave it in the soil for 30 mins.  After 30 mins take it out.  Look at it and touch it against your cheek.  If you eyes see a difference in the colour of the bamboo you know the soil is moist.  IF the colour change is significant the soil is wet.   But, sometimes its hard to tell, by touching the skewer against your cheek you will be able to tell if it is wet or dry.  Faces are more sensitive than hand when it comes to telling if something is wet.  This simple test is much more accurate than any moisture metre.

This is not an easy succulent to grow.  I have struggled on and off with this plant myself.  The soil needs to be extremely well draining.  The pot should be a terra-cotta clay pot.  Avoid glazed, plastic, & resin pot.  You want a pot that breaths.  You need the soil to dry out quickly. The pot must have holes in the bottom.